# What's the smallest kerolox engine that is/was used for spaceflight?

Tags: engines, identify-this-object

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32896/how-does-the-camera-make-the-exhaust-of-the-electrons-rp-1-lox-exhaust-transpar/33990#comment101560_32896) linked in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33990/12102) to the question *How does the camera make the exhaust of the Electron's RP-1/LOX exhaust transparent?* says

> Some quick calculation suggests the thickness of the exhaust plume from a Rutherford is about 1/6 that of a Merlin 1D, 1/18 that of an F-1.

This led me to wonder if the Rutherford is the smallest RP-1/LOX engine to be used in spaceflight.

1. Is it the smallest for orbital launches?
2. Have smaller ones been used for suborbital spaceflight for scientific purposes?

Comment: @RussellBorogove 470 Newton "rocket engine"! http://www.astronautix.com/p/p4-1sustainer.html this one stands out in a quick check, but I'm not sure it can go to space. "[The P4-1 (a.k.a. LR64) engine was also manufactured for the AQM-37A target drone.](https://www.wikizero.com/en/Rocketdyne)" so I guess not.

Comment: perhaps http://www.astronautix.com/r/rs-36sustainer.html at 9.21 kN.

Comment: To make your question a little more granular, does it matter if it's used singly or in multiples?

Comment: @Snoopy to me it doesn't matter, no. As long as it is involved in getting to space or being used in space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start off with a guess - the early Atlas LR-101 vernier engines, originally 669 lbf (as low as 526 lbf in some configurations), later upgraded to 1000 lbf.

Visible in this picture firing to left and right.

[image]

Beautiful image from [here](https://fineartamerica.com/featured/ranger-1-atlas-agena-rocket-launch-nasavrs.html)

[image]

Schematic from, and good information, [here](http://heroicrelics.org/info/lr-101/lr-101.html)

Cool picture of this little engine mounted on its pitch/yaw gimbal. It looks like a spotting scope. from [here](http://heroicrelics.org/mark-wells/engines-lr-101/dsc88332.jpg.html)

[image]

Comment: these aren't as small and didn't go to space, but they are kind-of cute https://youtu.be/pqCatb2oApU