# What is the lowest first stage thrust for a launch reaching orbit?

Tags: engines, record, thrust

What is the lowest thrust for a first stage rocket for a rocket that reached Earth orbit?

Comment: The shuttle's 6000 lbf OMS engines circularized the orbit. Does that count as "pushing into orbit"? How about the little verniers on the first stage of old Atlases?

Comment: I think the question is now what the OP intended, although I could be wrong here. There has only been one first stage engine to make it to orbit that I am aware of, the Space Shuttle main engines, but I think the first stage thrust for an orbital rocket is what is actually desired here.

Comment: Now I realized first stage engines do not actually reach orbit.

Comment: Thrust is the force what the drive creates, measured in Newton (N). The question is surely not VLQ (imho it is a pretty okay one, at least now).

Comment: Is the intention of the question thrust in absolute numbers or trust to weight ratio?

Comment: @lijat I don't know but 1) the OP has asked a series of absolute questions (shortest, smallest) so I'd guess it's the same absolute, 2) that makes for an *excellent new question!* e.g. Which launch "most barely" got off the pad? or Most gradual lift-off? The answer would obviously not be this: [Did the Perseverance rover's Atlas 5 really “leap off the pad”? If so, was it because the payload is tiny, or because it's going to Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45636/12102) :-)

Comment: The words "that have been achieved so far" were in the question at one point during the comedy of edits so far; such words are crucial in order for this to be a clear and meaningful question (assuming that's what the OP intended).

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto didn't Atlas stage and a half first stage engines make it to orbit?

Comment: There have been a few sub-2 stage rockets, but... It isn't common for sure!

Comment: Can you please re-phrase that Question? As it is, a useful Answer might as well be "Lots and none at all…"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The U.S. Vanguard rocket reached orbit three times with a first stage thrust of only 125 kN.

> The first stage of the three-stage Vanguard Test vehicle was powered by a GE X-405 **28,000 pound (~125,000 N)** thrust liquid rocket engine.

[Vanguard TV3 — NASA NSSDCA](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=VAGT3)

Answer (score 13):

**@2012campion's answer shows that this was not the lowest thrust**

The smallest rocket to reach orbit is the [Japanese SS520-5](https://spaceflight101.com/japan-ss-520-5-launch-success/). It had a peak thrust of $185 kN$ according to the same web page:

> Firing up its first stage, SS-520-5 shot up from its launch rail at 2:03:00 p.m. local time on Saturday with its aft fins sending the climbing rocket into a spin to provide stabilization as it climbed with a thrust outweighing the vehicle’s mass by a factor of seven. The first stage, standing 6.1 meters tall and holding 1,587 Kilograms of propellant, pushed the vehicle skyward with a peak thrust of 185 Kilonewtons (18,900 Kilogram-force), averaging at 143kN (14,600kgf) over the course of a 31.7-second burn.

I can't rule out that a slightly larger rocket nevertheless had a slightly lower thrust, but this must be close to the lowest.

Comment: That might be the smallest absolute thrust, but a launchpad TWR of 7 is far higher than most rockets have.

Comment: @JoeJobs This answer came *before* the one about Vanguard

Answer (score 9):

*Note: When this answer was written, the question read as follows:*

> **What is the lowest first stage rocket engine thrust for a rocket that reached Earth orbit?**

The first stage [vernier engines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_thruster) on early Atlas boosters were 526 lbf (2.3 kN).

Reference: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33998/6944

Comment: Given OP's recent history of questions, I assume they're asking for the lowest total-first-stage thrust rather than the lowest thrust of an individual engine.

Comment: @RussellBorogove you could, of course, be right.  The question has had an extensive edit history and the current version was not written by the OP. When I wrote the answer, the body said "What is the lowest first stage rocket engine thrust for a rocket that reached Earth orbit?"  I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Were they used for thrust or just for attitude adjustment?

Comment: Rockets are always used for thrust!  There's certainly a vertical component to the force from these verniers.

Comment: @JoeJobs I once referred to exhaust as thrust and these guys (appropriately) razzed me  extensively, or at least that's what I remember. :-) In this SE site "thrust" is just about any intentional propulsive force and many that are not. It could be from the tiniest nano-thruster or even the reflection of sunlight off of a paddle. If it's done on purpose and often even if its not, people will call it thrust. Just fyi in LEO the force of air molecules hitting a spacecraft is broken up into components parallel to velocity "drag" and perpendicular to it "lift" even though it's not an airplane.

Comment: Sorry I mean thrust used for pushing it into orbit. Those thruster used just for orientation or for docking ISS do not count

Comment: @JoeJobs: As you can see from the link, these engines fire at an angle, so *some* of their thrust contributes to upward / forward momentum.  But the only reason they're there  is for attitude control during ascent, not because their extra thrust is needed.  (They are low down on the *first* stage, so don't make it to orbit, and thus weren't involved in docking.  Also of course "early Atlas" means it predates the ISS by a long time, but other things have docked in Earth orbit, including test-runs for how Apollo's 2 modules would reconnect.)