# Rocket engine with lowest Isp to reach orbit

Tags: rockets, orbit, engines, engine-design, specific-impulse

Which engine with the lowest possible specific impulse has reached orbit propelling a given rocket? There is a [page at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_rocket_engines) that compares orbital engines but some engines are missing Isp value and the list may be incomplete. The lowest Isp listed so far is the Indian SLV-1 on [Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle) with an impulse of 253 seconds.

I am primarily interested in first stage engines but mentioning other stages is possible. I guess flying a low Isp engine is difficult since your rocket have to be bigger (needs more fuel because of inefficient engine).

Related question: [What is the lowest first stage thrust for a launch reaching orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48198/what-is-the-lowest-first-stage-thrust-for-a-launch-reaching-orbit)

Answer (score 3):

There may be some cases where something like the Atlas vernier rockets contribute a little bit to thrust and have a significantly lower Isp than the primary first-stage engines.

As for primary first-stage engines, the US's earliest orbital rockets in the years 1958-1960 used relatively inefficient engines.

[Vanguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_(rocket)) used a liquid rocket engine (kerosene/LOX) on the first stage with 248 s specific impulse. The third stage was a solid with 230 s Isp.

[Juno I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_I) was an even poorer performer, at 235 s on the first stage (Hydyne/LOX).

[Scout X-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_X-1) and its sibling [Blue Scout II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RM-90_Blue_Scout_II), which, although designed as sounding rockets, did manage orbital launches, used 236 s solid rocket first stages.

Comment: Wow! great numbers.

Comment: 1958 was another country.