# Why does the Shenzhou-12 spacecraft appear square in this picture?

Tags: capsule, shenzhou

In [this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-58554332), the attached image, captioned "The Shenzhou-12 capsule bears the scorch marks from the heat of re-entry," really caught my eye - it looks like they dropped a shipping container from space! I googled the Shenzhou-12 immediately and every other picture seems to show a normal circular spacecraft, so what exactly am I seeing in the image on the BBC?

[image: The offending image]

Comment: I think your eye is simply misguided by the equipment and the flag in the foreground that obscure the round shape. The harsh shadow on the bottom edge doesn't help either.

Comment: @asdfex I mean it's possible? But the corner in the top right seems pretty undeniably square to me

Comment: There's no corner there. It's just the edge where the cylindrical black part and the rounded, sand-colored cap meet.  It's hard to grasp because of the total lack of a color or brightness gradient in this area due to the uniform illumination. After glancing at the image from some other angles I also was able to convince my brain that it's a box shape...

Comment: See also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16926/6944 for a similar illusion.

Comment: It's square because... it isn't? You are looking at the side bottom of a near cylinder. The black bit is a curved surface spanning more than 170 degrees of arc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As asdfex says, it's an illusion caused by the photo angle and lighting, the cylindrical sides form a sharp angle with the (very much flattened) base.

This photo shows the base of a Shenzhou spacecraft from a slightly different angle.

[image]

*Image credit: theregister.com*

As you can see, the base is convex, not flat, and its circumference has a ring of evenly spaced indentations and raised features:

[[image]][2

compare this to the image you posted...

[image]

these marks are widely spaced in the middle  but close together at the top and bottom, a typical perspective effect.

Comment: Wow. That's definitely a bit mind bending. What a weird trick of perspective.

Comment: @uhoh  Me too at first glance!  I thing the flag on the left leads the eye to extend the line of the capsule but actually there's a sharp curve from the side to the hatch at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to overlay a side-view diagram of the Shenzhou reentry capsule (borrowed from [this wikipedia diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_(spacecraft)#/media/File:Shenzhou_spacecraft_vector_diagram.svg), and adapted for transparency) on top of your photo:

[image: photo with overlaid diagram]

Now your brain is seeing through the optical illusion: one of the flags is obscuring the curve of the capsule's top, and you can realize that the bottom-left corner is not the capsule itself, but rather an opened hatch or some other piece of equipment.